# To show that the integral of a certain series converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers converging to $0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \log(1/a_n)<\infty$. Further, let $b_n$ be an arbitrary sequence and define

$$f_n(x):=\begin{cases} 
      \cfrac{a_n}{|x-b_n|}, &  a_n\leq |x-b_n| \\
       0, & \text{else} \\
   \end{cases}
$$

I would like to show that for every $R>0$, $$\int_{-R}^R\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \;dx<\infty.$$

My attempt is to interchange the integral and sum (MCT allows this since $f_n$ is non-negative and partial sums are increasing) and then evaluate the integral of $f_n$. However, for large enough $R$, this integral must be divergent since $b_n\in [-R,R]$, for large enough $R$, so I think this will not work. Any hints?

Please don't answer this problem in its entirety, I would very much like to do it myself. Thanks for you time.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Why do you think the integral must be divergent if $b_n \in [-R,R]$?

Comment: $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq 1$. So the integral is finite for any $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: I'm guessing the $1/|x-b_n|$ term in the integrand has got you confused. Indeed, if $b_n\in [-R,R],$ then

$$\int_{-R}^R \frac{dx}{|x-b_n|}dx= \infty.$$

But that is not the integral we are dealing with. Suppose $b_n=0$ for example. Assuming $a_n<R,$ the integral of interest is

$$\int_{a_n\le|x|\le R} \frac{dx}{|x|}dx= 2\ln(R/a_n).$$

Comment: Hi zhw. I'm interested in this problem. Could you please help me? The integral is $\int_{-R}^{b_n-a_n}\cfrac{a_n}{b_n-x}dx+\int_{b_n+a_n}^R\cfrac{a_n}{x-b_n}dx$, right? If so, this evaluates to $a_n(\log(\cfrac{R-b_n}{R+n_n}))$. I'm not sure how to tell if the series $\sum a_n \log(\cfrac{R-b_n}{R+n_n})$ converges.